# Escape $ sign using sed

Tags: bash, templates, sed

I have a string in file a:

```
  my_password: "@$hp!sN0t"
```

I want to escape the dollar sign by adding a backslash before it using sed. The output file b should contain:

```
  my_password: "@\$hp!sN0t"
```

I used the command:

```
sed 's/\$/\\$/g' a >b
```

And it works well.

But I want to skip escaping the dollar signs that are purposefully used for variables in the file.

For example, `${KEY_FILE_URI}` is a variable mentioned inside the same file and its dollar sign should not be escaped.

Otherwise, the command should be able to replace the `$` with `\$` only if the `$` comes inside double-quotes.

The other way is to use a second command to relace the \${ in file b with ${ and write to file c.

```
sed 's/\\${/${/g' b >c
```

Is there any simpler method for this? How can I do that correctly?

Comment: Your problem arises from how you're trying to programmatically edit a script instead of just writing a good script. What is the nature/purpose of file a?

Comment: @vintnes What I am trying to do is to create a new b.yaml file by replacing some lines of a.tmpl file. Since a YAML is created from tmpl, some formatting issues related to quotes arises. That's why i am using sed to fix those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\$[^{]/\\&/g' file
```

If the character following a `$` is not a `{`, then insert a `\` before the `$`.

Comment: This relies on variables always using curly braces, though – breaks for `$myvar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on metaprogramming:

```
awk '$1 == "my_password:" {gsub(/\$/, "\\$")} 1' a
```

On lines wherein the first field (word) is `"my_password:"`, perform a global substitution: literal dollar signs (not end-of-line regex markers) are replaced by literal backslashes followed by literal dollar signs. The `1` effectively means `true` and will perform the default action (print record) for all records. It could be written `{print}` or `{print $0}`.